# Brantree set-up in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, braintree

I have set-up `brain-tree` via `composer` in `laravel 5.0` from `GitHub`.
I have added `"oureastudios/laravel5-braintree": "dev-master"` to my `composer.json` file and then run composer update command. After that i added `'Oureastudios\Laravel\BraintreeServiceProvider',` in `porivders` array in `app.php` file. I have set-up everything but i just want to know how to call BraintreeServiceProvider.php class exists in vendor/oureastudios/laravel5-braintree/src/Oureastudios/Laravel/ in controller. i have used use `Oureastudios\Laravel\BraintreeServiceProvider;` in controller and make a function `braintree()`. Now i want to create customer by calling create method of Braintree_Customer class but it will give me an error Class `'App\Http\Controllers\frontEnd\Braintree_Customer'` not found. Could anyone help how to resolve this problem. Thanks..

```
public function braintree() {

$result = Braintree_Customer::create([
        'firstName' => 'Mike',
        'lastName'  => 'Jones',
        'company'   => 'Jones Co.',
        'email'     => 'mike.jones@example.com',
        'phone'     => '281.330.8004',
        'fax'       => '419.555.1235',
        'website'   => 'http://example.com'
]);

prx($result);die;

}
```

Comment: Try to put a slash in front of the class to use outside of your controller namespace, like this `$result = \Braintree_Customer::create([...`.

Comment: It works perfectly thanks....:)